# How to do readable.pause() in node.js so that readable.on('end', function(){}) is not emitted?

Tags: node.js

I am consuming a bunch of data in my express node.js app. I have to wait for one of my operations to finish before consuming more data.

```
req.on('data', function(data) {
  req.pause();
  do_my_thing();
  req.resume();
}
req.on('end', function() {
  do_my_finish_thing();
}
```

The problem is that req.on('end', (){}) gets called even if I pause the stream. Is there a way to pause the stream so that on('end', (){}) is not emitted?

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, but the 'do_my_thing function will be executed asynchronously, therefore, it'll resume almost instantaneously.

You can resume the stream in the callback of do_my_thing :

```
function do_my_thing(callback){
   //do your thing 
   callback();
}

req.on('data', function(data) {
    req.pause();
    do_my_thing(function(){
        req.resume();
    });
}
req.on('end', function() {
  do_my_finish_thing();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's actually like that, what you wrote. Do_my_thing also has a callback, and the callback resumes the stream. The problem is the same: if there is no more data left, req.on('end',(){}) will get called while the stream is paused.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with the following. Suggestions to improve are appreciated.

```
function do_my_thing(callback){
   //do your thing 
   callback();
}
function do_my_finish_thing(){};

var is_processable = false;
req.on('data', function(data) {
    req.pause();
    is_processable = false;
    do_my_thing(function(){
        req.resume();
        is_processable = true;
    });
}
req.on('end', function() {
  function doit() {
    if (is_processable) {
      do_my_finish_thing();
    } else {
      setTimeout(doit, 100);
    }
  }
  doit();
}
```

Comment: Did you find a better solution ? 
Thanks !